# Zend_Soap client and SoapServer UTF-8 encoding problem

Tags: utf-8, zend-soap

The site works on one server and DB on the other server. When I enter on site text to submit to DB on non english letters, it saves and ther render corect. For example if I enter "**Привет Всем**" I will see the same text on the site when display.

All MySQL collation as table as fields are utf8_general_ci
Meta content-encoding on the page also utf-8 as on site as on phpMyAdmin

Although if I access DB with phpMyAdmin I see ÐšÐ¾Ð½ÑÑ‚Ð½Ð°Ñ‚Ð¸Ð½ ÐŸÐ°Ð
If I change it to Привет Всем then on the site I see ???????? ????

It was not working like this on our local test on 2 different servers with Windows on them. But after deploy to centOS online server it bacome work like this.

Looks like it double encode text to UTF-8. I cannot find where is it.

Zend_Soap_Client:: or SoapServer:: or MySQL encoding.

I rejected idea of Mysql because I though that if it is MySQl then it saves wrong, and then when it extraxts it should send wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to configure Zend_Soap_Client or SoapServer to use **utf8**?
In case of Zend_Soap_Client it can be done like this:

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client("http://my.site/my.wsdl", array('encoding' => 'UTF-8'));
```